# minimum steps by 1 or 2 but divisible by given number

Tags: python-3.x

I am working on a python program where I want to find the minimum number of steps needed to reach a top floor such that the count of steps should be divisible by given number say `m`

Here is my program taken from [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/count-ways-reach-nth-stair/):

```
# A program to count the number of ways to reach n'th stair 

# Recurssive program to find n'th fibonacci number 
def fib(n): 
    if n <= 1: 
        return n 
    return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2) 

# returns no. of ways to reach s'th stair 
def countWays(s): 
    return fib(s + 1) 

# Driver program 

s = 10
print("Number of ways = ", countWays(s) )
```

Here I am getting the total number of ways, but I want to filter them by those divisible by a given number say `m`, how to do this?

```
Example:
1) s = 10 and m = 2, output should be 6, as the steps are {2,2,2,2,1,1}

2) s = 3 and m = 5 output should be -1 as the possible steps are {1,1,1}, {2,1}, {1,2}  
--> here none of them (means 3 steps, 2 steps, 2 steps) are divible by 5.
```

Comment: `but I want to filter them by those divisible by a given number say m, how to do this` can you explain what this means? Please give a result for `countWays(s)` and what you then expect that result to be in the modified function. How is 89 divisible by 2 6 times?

Comment: @JerryM., I added examples at the end of the question, please check.

Comment: Those examples make absolutely no sense without an explanation @learner

Comment: @JerryM., added explanation now

Comment: Where do `steps are {2,2,2,2,1,1}` come from???? and only 3 of those are divisible by 2????

Comment: `{2,2,2,2,1,1}` sum of each elements 2+2+2+2+1+1=10, so this is matching with s = 10. Next, length of this array is `6` which is divisible by `m=2`. This is the minimum combination of steps to get 10 and also divisible by 2

Answer (score 0):

```
s = 10
m = 2
if s % m == 0:
    print(s)

outputs: 10
```

Using % is a modulo operation. This provides a "remainder" after division. So if your item has no remainder, it is divisible by the selected number.

```
# A program to count the number of ways to reach n'th stair 

# Recursive function used by countWays 
def countWaysUtil(n,m): 
    res = [0 for x in range(n)] # Creates list res witth all elements 0 
    res[0],res[1] = 1,1

    for i in range(2,n): 
        j = 1
        while j<=m and j<=i: 
            res[i] = res[i] + res[i-j] 
            j = j + 1 
    return res[n-1] 

# Returns number of ways to reach s'th stair 
def countWays(s,m): 
    return countWaysUtil(s+1, m) 

# Driver Program 
s,m = 4,2
print "Number of ways =",countWays(s,m) 

# Contributed by Harshit Agrawal
```

Comment: I added sample inputs by updating my question, can you please check, the output is not matching for your program when I run it.

Comment: For input s = 10 and m = 2, output should be 6, but your answer is still giving 89. Please refer to sample inputs and expected outputs I added to my question

Answer (score -1):

You can use this:

```
# A program to count the number of ways to reach n'th stair 

# Recurssive program to find n'th fibonacci number 
def fib(n): 
    if n <= 1: 
        return n 
    return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2) 

# returns no. of ways to reach s'th stair 
def countWays(s, m): 
    # Add in a division by m, which you pass to the function
    # Cast it as an int to return a whole # and not decimal
    return int(fib(s + 1) / m)

# Driver program 

s = 10
# Set this to whatever
m = 3
print("Number of ways = ", countWays(s, m) )
```

Comment: I added sample inputs by updating my question, can you please check, the output is not matching for your program when I run it. It is giving 44 instead of 6

Comment: `int(fib(s + 1) / m` for `fib` returning `int` and `int` `m` is a slow (and for large numbers, inaccurate) way to spell `fib(s + 1) // m`. Never do it that way, always use `//` for direct integer floor division. Not addressing whether the code is correct or not (haven't looked at it closely), but `int(x / y)` for `int` `x` and `y` is basically always wrong.

Comment: This answer (in its current state) doesn't make sense -- still trying to derive requirements from OP. Thanks for the tip, @ShadowRanger